# How to call other phone in the same house and network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, voip, phone

I have an analog phone (Panasonic KX-TS505MX) and it is connected to my modem router (ZTE F660) via POTS. My router modem have 2 POTS slot, my question is if I buy another phone, is it possible to call between 2 phones locally?

The reason is I want to setup another phone inside the house so I can talk to other family member without hassle.

Where do I start and what kind of device would I need (free is preffered of course)?

Comment: Why not just buy a set of cordless phones that have an intercom facility? Connect the base station to your router and all extensions can make outgoing calls and also call each other. See http://shop.panasonic.com/home-and-office/cordless-corded-telephones/cordless-telephones for some possibilities

Comment: Note that your 2 pots ports will only be active if you are paying for two telephone connections from your provider (and they would have different numbers).